# Retrieving html data from database to create a page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have stored html file in database. Now I would like to get data using cs file and link it to my view page. Below is my example of how I have save my able.

My database table contains two columns (**page_header, page_footer**).

**page_header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
```

**page_footer**

```
<footer>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>.<br>
Visit us at:<br>
Example.com<br>
Box 564, Disneyland<br>
USA
</td>
<td>
<a href="www.google.com">Visit our Site </a>
</td>
</footer>
```

I want to retrieve those data to my aspx page. Can anyone help in doing that. Or if any demo is available which will be helpful understand how to do that.

If this post is not related please don't degrade. Just let me know, I will delete it.

Comment: That is fine if you're serving plain HTML with no server-side markup. In such a case, you can use three DIVS in your page and fill them using DIV.INNTERHTML on Init or Load. The question, though, is WHY do you want to limit yourself by serving plain HTML from a database instead of serving database content into parsed HTML? What is the purpose of storing your entire page in the DB?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger The reason is page data changes as per customer. the above html is just an example.

Comment: Yeah - understood. But use <div id="customerName" runat="server"> and customerName.InnerHtml = "Welcome back, Mr. Everett!" rather than serving the entire page from DB. Think about it - if you change your HTML, you will have to update EVERY customer record you have BY HAND! ASP.NET is DESIGNED to do what you want. You really should go in a more traditional way.

Comment: Everything about ASP.NET is designed to serve rich, user-specific content in an easy, convenient manner. You CAN load an entire page of HTML and send it with response.Write or Div.innerHtml, but I'm telling you with extreme prejudice that you don't WANT to do that - there be nothing but pain and sorrow down the road you are walking!

Comment: I see you've changed your post to exclude page content. You're on the right track, but you don't want to write header/footer from DB, either - ASP.Net has methods for serving those as well. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178795.aspx

Comment: The reason you are getting voted down - people are trying to tell you that this is a BAD IDEA!!! Hey - we've all had them. I'm not picking on you, I'm trying to save you a lot of pain down the road. Learn how to serve customer-specific content through an existing web page. PLEASE!!! For all our sakes!

Comment: Let me tell you in brief what I am doing. I am creating a page which will get header and footer based on specific ID. This ID is specified on the link. So when they click my above request will open. And body tag is also from the database which will get customer's detail. So according to that I am creating a page. Hope I delivered my explanation properly. This is like a requirement. for me.

Comment: Please see the example in my answer of how to serve user-specific data. There is no reason for you to store your entire HTML in the database. It's bad on resources, it's impossible to update or change, and it's like buying a Ferrari and hitching a horse to it to drive around town. It's not necessary and BAD **BAD** practice! At least take a day or so to figure out how ASP.NET works before committing to this horrible path of pain and suffering!

Comment: Think - if you do this, buttons won't work. Textboxes won't work. NOTHING works - just a static page the user can't interact with in any way. That sound like a good website to you? I hope not!!

Comment: Yes. I know. I have a simple text page. without buttons and textboxes. User just have to look at the details that's it. There are no other functionality besides showing Customer Details in body part. Also that detaiils is shown in datagrid.

Comment: Still, if you have 100,000 users, you have 100,000 copies of the HTML when you only need one. If you change it ever you will have to change it 100,000 times. If you insist on doing this, look at Response.Write and/or Div.InnerHtml.

Comment: You're going to try to fill a datagrid without benefit of codebehind? Good luck, friend -- I've tried as hard as I can to convince you to do it properly. It's up to you to learn how horrible things are going to be. Best of luck!

Comment: Obviously there will be code behind to get data. But anyways, thank you very much to look into my request. Appreciate that you took out some time for this.

Comment: There won't be codebehind to get data if you serve your entire page by response! That's what I'm trying to tell you! You won't have access to codebehind! Sheesh! Ah, well, you'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get user-specific information to your user without having to hand-update every single page you ever serve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title runat="server">Page Title</title>
</head>
<body runat="server">
    <div id="welcomeDiv" runat="server"></div>
    <div id="dataDiv" runat="server">
         <datagridview id = "customerData" runat="server">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

then, in your codebehind file:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //load name from db
      Form1.Title = "Welcome back, Mr. "+customer.LastName;
      welcomeDIV.InnerHtml = "<b>It's been "+customer.daysSinceLastVisit.ToString()+" days since you last visited! How are "+customer.wifeName+" and the boys?</b>";
      customerData = loadDataGrid(customer.ID);
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you are helping. I know how to get body data. But there are many different headers and footers based on ID. That ID will serve as per my customers. So I am keeping my solution project simple and getting data from database.

Comment: Loading information from a DB into an existing DIV is far more simple than storing 1,000 different mirrored sets of HTML. It's painful to think about.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating some kind of a multi-tenant system and need a small amount of customization for each tenant.

There is no reason not to store HTML templates in a database—CMSes such as Wordpress do that a lot. However, to @ShannonHolsinger's point, you should ensure that your database schema is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) to a reasonable extent. Consider storing e-mail address, contact name, address and website URL as separate fields.

For a templating system, there are many types of choices. You should explore some so you can choose one that is most familiar to you or your needs. In every case, though, be sure that data is property escaped to HTML or you could be allowing your page to be taken over. If you just paste strings together, such as by using `InnerHtml` then someone could enter their name as `</div><script>ChangeTheEntirePageToWhatEverILike()</script>` or `</div><script>InjectInSomeCodeToSendFormDataToMySite()</script>` and it would be seen by the browser as your code rather than as text.

One templating technique could involve client-side data binding. Some popular libraries are Knockout and Angular 2. For client-side data binding, you could put variable references in trusted header and footer HTML and then pass the variable values to be bound as JavaScript data. In other words, let the browser do any data merging that's needed rather than ASP.NET.